# Checking if file exists using $.ajax() problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am having a problem checking if a file exists using $.ajax(). I am looping through a json file with $.each and I want to see if the specified staff member has an image, and if not use the no_photo.jpg image. I keep getting the no_photo.jpg image even though there is the staff member's image in the directory.

Here is the entire $.getJSON() call.

```
$.getJSON('staff.json', function(data) {
                var last_check;
                var image_url = "no_photo";
              $.each(data.employees, function(i,employee){
                if ((i+1)%4==0) {last_check = " last";} else {last_check = "";}
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/images/staff/' + employee.first_name.toLowerCase() + employee.last_name.toLowerCase() + '.jpg',
                    type:'HEAD',
                    error:
                        function(){
                            image_url = "no_photo";
                        },
                    success:
                        function(){
                            image_url = employee.first_name.toLowerCase() + employee.last_name.toLowerCase();
                        }
                });
                $("div.staff-members").append('<a href="#" title="' + employee.first_name + ' ' + employee.last_name + ', ' + employee.title + '" rel="' + employee.location + '" class="' + employee.category + last_check + '"><img src="/images/staff/' + image_url + '.jpg"><span class="' + employee.category + '"></span></a>');
              });
            });
```

Comment: Check manually the url you are requesting in the $.ajax request and give us details on the answer.

Comment: BTW, you are making a lot of HTTP requests (1 + 2*N in the worst case), I should try to minimize them to speed up your page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend **not** to use jQuerys `.ajax()` (or any other XHR) method for that purpose. Use `Javascripts` Image object instead.

```
var testimg = new Image();
testimg.onload = function(){
    if(this.width > 0)
       image_url = this.src;
    else
       image_url = "no_photo";

    $("div.staff-members").append('<a href="#" title="' + employee.first_name + ' ' + employee.last_name + ', ' + employee.title + '" rel="' + employee.location + '" class="' + employee.category + last_check + '"><img src="/images/staff/' + image_url + '.jpg"><span class="' + employee.category + '"></span></a>');
};
testimg.onerror = function(){
    image_url = "no_photo";
    $("div.staff-members").append('<a href="#" title="' + employee.first_name + ' ' + employee.last_name + ', ' + employee.title + '" rel="' + employee.location + '" class="' + employee.category + last_check + '"><img src="/images/staff/' + image_url + '.jpg"><span class="' + employee.category + '"></span></a>');
};
testimg.src = '/images/staff/' + employee.first_name.toLowerCase() + employee.last_name.toLowerCase() + '.jpg';
```

This has less overhead than an `Ajax request`.

**update**

moved the `.src =` instruction to the bottom (msie requires this, credits to Nick Craver)

Since this approach uses asynchronous callbacks (as does `.ajax()`), you need to call your `.append()` within the event handlers.

Comment: You would need to change your order around here, attaching an `onload` handler *after* setting the `src` won't fire your handler in many cases, as the event already occurred when it comes from cache.

Comment: @Nick: actually, no you don't have to do that. Well at least I never had a problem by using this order, cache or not. Can you give a usecase for your statement?

Comment: @jAndy - Sure, you can see a simple test here, try it in IE, even IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/qNFxq/ after the first load you won't get an alert...move the `.src` *after* the `onload` and you'll consistently get the alert :)

Comment: @Nick: I see, interesting. Chrome/Safari & Firefox perform as expected regardless of the order, so it seems to be another very own MSIE behavior.

Comment: @jAndy - Another thing is your answer doesn't address the async issue, `image_url` will still be `"no_photo" every time with your answer, it needs to actually call the append when the load or error happens  :)

Comment: @Nick: I didn't mention a lot since I was only suggesting a (IMO) better way to accomplish that task :)

Comment: @jAndy - Oh I realize that, I deleted b/c I agree this is a much better approach, but without mentioning that the `image_url` is `"no_photo" because no success or error function sets it...well the OP's back to the original problem the current question has :)

Comment: @Nick: fair enough, convinced.